# The sum of elements of a set equals the product of another one .(Math contest)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, contest-math

> We say that a natural number $n\ge 2$ is SP (i don’t what does that mean), if we can split the set $$S=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$$ into two nonempty subsets, (They don’t share any common element) such that the sum the first subset equals the product of the second one. Example: $n=7$ Is SP because $2+4+5+7=1
> \cdot 3 \cdot 6$
>
> 1. prove that $n=4$ is not SP
> 2. check whether or not $6$ and $7$ are SP
> 3. Prove that all $n\ge 7$ are SP

This is the problem number $3$ (which is the last one) in a math Olympiad in which i participated yesterday.

I didn’t do any question from these $3$ Ones (i mean the questions of the third problem), i thought that the best way to do the first question is to just guess and check cases, but i realized that there is a lot of cases the check so this method is not good, and then i’ve tried to find a general way but i didn’t get anything.

Comment: Guess and check for part 1 is great. There are <20 cases. For part 3, find a pattern by checking $n = 7, 8, 9, ...$ as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly different way of doing this:

$$n=8: \quad 8 \times 3 \times 1 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^8 i\right)-8-3-1$$

$$n=9:  \quad 8 \times 4 \times 1 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^8 i\right)-3-1 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^8 i\right)+9-8-4-1 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^9 i\right) -8-4-1.$$

We now find a way of partitioning.
Assume the following for an even integer $n$:

> (IH): $$n \times \left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right) \times 1 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)-n-\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)-1.$$

Then

$$n \times \left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \times 1 = n+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)-n-\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)-1$$
$$=n+1+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)-n-\frac{n}{2}-1 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i\right)-n - \frac{n}{2} - 1
.$$
So $n+1$ is SP.

And

$$(n+2) \times \frac{n}{2} \times 1 = 2n+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)-n-\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)-1
=(n+1) + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)-\frac{n}{2}-1$$
$$=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i\right)- \frac{n}{2}-1 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+2} i\right)-(n+2) - \frac{n}{2}-1.$$
So $n+2$ is SP as well, and (IH) holds when $n$ is replaced with $n+2$.

Comment: You used an induction at the end? I didn’t think of that when i was in the Olympiad @Mike

Comment: @Yassir Pattern recognition / case checking / induction is quite natural for a question like  this. In fact, the induction here "hides" what is going on, esp since the statement can be checked directly like Tom did.

Comment: Frankly I like @TomTom314 's answer better than mine and I think his is the best answer here and should be the one accepted. No induction needed!

Answer (score 2):

1: The SP-value has an upper bound $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Therefore for $n=4$ we get $|SP|<10$ and the product contains either $3$ or $4$. This reduces the  product values to $|SP|\in\{3,4,6,8\}$ - just 4 cases to check.

2,3: Using the example $2+4+5+7=6\cdot 3\cdot 1\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^7 k = 6\cdot 3\cdot 1 + 6+3+1$ we get a good starting point for a general formula. For odd numbers $2n+1$ we can use $$(2n+1)(n+1) = 2n\cdot n \cdot 1 + 2n +n+1$$ and for even $2n$:
$$n(2n+1) = 2n\cdot (n-1) \cdot 1 + 2n +(n-1)+1 .$$